# Why chrome's lighthouse audit is not working with ace Texteditor

Tags: ace-editor, lighthouse

Why I cannot do lighthouse audit for the webpages that uses Ace Text editor.
For example: Try to audit this page (https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) you will get the following error

PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT

```
Channel: DevTools
Initial URL: https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html
Chrome Version: 86.0.4233.0
Stack Trace: LHError: PROTOCOL_TIMEOUT
    at eval (devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@5dd861d2c192ae8bf0c654dc35ff42b2ce0f6558/lighthouse_worker/lighthouse_worker_module.js:1589:229)
```

**Note**: Lighthouse can audit a webpage  that uses codemirror Text Editor (https://codemirror.net/demo/theme.html).

1. Why its happening?
2. Is it a serious SEO problem when choosing Ace as my Text editor?

Comment: seems to be a bug in lighthouse, it "says if this is reproducible, please report it at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse?

Comment: as usual they duplicated it.